# Out of the box support for deployment in wintersmith

Tags: node.js, heroku, github-pages, wintersmith

Is there an automated way to easily host a static site made with [wintersmith](http://wintersmith.io) on Github Pages or Heroku?

I have tried writing a gruntfile, shell scripts and a couple of suggestions that were mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/jnordberg/wintersmith/issues/151) but all of them were quite difficult to setup.

I am basically looking for something as simple as this -

```
wintersmith new myblog
npm install
wintersmith deploy
```

**PS:**
Can someone put a new wintersmith tag to this question?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some general guidelines based on my set up for github pages. ([more info on github pages](https://help.github.com/categories/20/articles))

I have two folders. One for wintersmith, and one which is a git repository folder.

```
./myblog/ (wintersmith)
./personalblog/ (git repo)
```

On configuring your git repo, create `./personalblog/` via:

```
mkdir personalblog; cd personalblog
git init
git branch -m master gh-pages (this is important! see: https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#project-pages)
```

Create a repository of the same name on github. Then set the origin of the local repo. [See here for more info.](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote#what-can-i-push-to)

Within `./myblog` I'd have a bash script (build.sh) with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ./myblog/build.sh

# other build commands such as javascript or css minifiers

rm -r ./build/
wintersmith build
```

Then, I check and verify the wintersmith build. I verify using [nodejs http-server](https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server). I'd have another bash script file for deployment:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ./myblog/deploy.sh

# rsync to efficiently sync ./myblog/build to ./personalblog/
# ignore deleteing .git folder and other stuff
rsync -rtvu --delete -f"- .git/" -f"- CNAME" -f"- .gitignore" -f"- README.md" ./build/ ../personalblog/


# change dir
cd ../personalblog/

# sync to github
git add -A
git commit -am "Commit on $(date)"
git push origin gh-pages
```

Hopefully these guidelines are helpful for you.

Comment: To be honest, it seems an unnecessary feature for wintersmith since deployment solutions are very specialized for a service/platform. Anyways, it isn't hard to set up a simple deployment script.

Comment: if you compare it with other platforms such as wordpress, octopress and a lot of others, they all have built in support for deploying to gh-pages and heroku. This feature completes `wintersmith` as a package. Writing scripts for publishing negates it for evaluation purposes.

Comment: You're free to make an octopress-like framework for wintersmith. But honestly, wintersmith should just do one thing and do it well (akin to the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)), which is to generate static pages. Things like deployment becomes [feature creeping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep). So far, most users of wintersmith are power users, and they should have no problem finding ways to easily augment what they want.

Comment: "most users of wintersmith are power users" That's a bit circular! Maybe there’d be more normal users if there was an easy to use deployment script?

Comment: Also, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145621/how-to-publish-pages-on-github and this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/push-dir