# How to publish pages on Github?

Tags: github

Looks simple, I'm reading a lot about but I'm having issues to do it.

```
git add .
git commit -m "documentation improvements"
git push -u origin master
git push -u origin gh-pages

error: src refspec gh-pages does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/danielfpedro/simple-modal
.git'
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[this](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-manually) documentation might help. ie:

#### 1) Get out of current repo and make a fresh clone:

```
cd ..
git clone https://github.com/danielfpedro/simple-modal.git simple-modal-webpage
```

#### 2) Create a gh-pages branch(without any parents) and remove all content from the working directory and index:

```
cd simple-modal-webpage
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git rm -rf .
```

#### 3) Add content and push

```
echo "My GitHub Page" > index.html
git add index.html
git commit -a -m "First pages commit"
git push origin gh-pages
```

After your push to the `gh-pages` branch, your Project Page will be available at `danielfpedro.github.io/simple-modal`

#### 4) Delete the cloned folder(`simple-modal-webpage`) and pull the branch `gh-pages` in original repo(`simple-modal`):

```
cd ..
rm -r simple-modal-webpage
cd simple-modal
git fetch --all
git checkout -b gh-pages origin/gh-pages   #New git just use --> git checkout gh-pages
```

#### 5) that is it, now you have 1 more branch `gh-pages`. use it to commit changes for github webpage:

```
git checkout gh-pages
<made changes to documentation>
git add .
git commit -m "documentation improvements"
git push -u origin gh-pages
```

Comment: I still dont get it. Everytime that i want publish a page changes I have to clone the repo and do it?

Comment: @DanielFaria what about clone it with different directoryname. so no conflict with the current repos directory name. ie `git clone https://github.com/danielfpedro/simple-modal.git simple-modal-webpage`

Comment: @DanielFaria after initial git push then delete the folder `simple-modal-webpage` and pull the changes in `simple-modal` dir- ie: `git pull origin gh-pages` --> now change it and pull it further

Comment: I could not have the webpage and the plugin in the same repo?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set up a new "orphan" branch in your repository? If not do this from your repository:

```
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
```

And create some content:

```
echo "Sample" > index.html
git add index.html
git commit -a -m "Sample page"
git push origin gh-pages
```

Now you should see your page (after some minutes).

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

If you're using `npm` use https://www.npmjs.com/package/push-dir.
The solution below still works if you're using something else to build your site.

**OLD ANSWER**

This approach doesn't force you to remove your build or dist folder from your .gitignore file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BUILD_DIR=build

git checkout -b _build_staging_
git add -f $BUILD_DIR
git commit -am add_build_ouput
git subtree split --prefix $BUILD_DIR -b gh-pages
git push origin gh-pages -f
git checkout -
git branch -D gh-pages _build_staging_
```

For my node project I added this to my package.json file under the scripts section and I called it "push" so that I can execute `npm run push` in the terminal to push the built output to gh-pages.